# Grabbing the innerHTML when there is no element, just text

Tags: javascript, html

I have some odd html provided by my website's platform. There is some html that looks like so:

```
<div class="report-description-text">
<h5>Description</h5>
Welcome to Ushahidi. Please replace this report with a valid incident
<br/>
</div>
```

I'd like to grab the text "Welcome to Ushahidi.." With help of a recent post I have managed to get close, but am not able to get what I need.

In the console of Chrome's inspect element feature if I type:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')[0].children[0].innerHTML
```

This returns "Description" - the innerHTML of the H5 element.

If the text "Welcome to Ushahidi..." was wrapped in say a `<p>` element I could have written

```
document.getElementsByClassName('report-description-text')[0].children[1].innerHTML
```

But since it's just text I am unable to grab it.

I looked at the selector in inspect element in Chrome and it just says (text) adjacent to the parent divs name (See bottom row of attached screenshot.
[image]

How do I grab the text in this instance?

---

Image of what I've tried after answer below:
[image]

Comment: I guess you are trying to replace the content of report-description-text? Why not just use this selector and replace it's html? or remove the whole div and insert your new block?

Comment: @Godinall no I'm trying to create metatags for search and social open graph. This particular one is going to form the description meta tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("report-description-text")[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
```

`nodeValue` is how you get the text of a text node, however browsers can be temperamental when it comes to text nodes (some will consider the fact that the `<h5>` is on a new line as there being a text node before it, throwing off the `[1]` in the above code)

Ideally, anything you will want to access by JavaScript should be in its own element, so consider adjusting the HTML if you can.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still struggling here. I'm going to attache an image of what I've tried based on your answer and the output in console

Comment: got it! you were right, it threw of the 1. Changed [1] to [2]

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="report-description-text">
<h5>Description</h5>
Welcome to Ushahidi. Please replace this report with a valid incident
<br/>
</div>
```

Assuming the structure does not change much, you can do this:

```
var node = document.querySelectorAll(".report-description-text h5")[0]
    .nextSibling;
console.log(node.nodeValue);
```

Alternate:

```
var node = document.getElementsByClassName("report-description-text")[0]
    .getElementsByTagName("h5")[0]
    .nextSibling;
console.log(node.nodeValue);
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/Lq3Ba/)

Note: The `.childNodes[1]` approach could be failing because the div contains whitespace before the h5 element and its children would be:

```
[0] #text (whitespace)
[1] <h5>
[2] #text (the node you want)
[3] <br>
```